# Why does reactivity break for only one variable in this CodeSandbox example?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity, composable

Can somebody explain to me why reactivity breaks for `number` in this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-reactivity-issue-4rto59?file=/public/index.html

I have 2 composables (useNumber.js and useRandomNumber.js) which I both **spread** in the return of the `setup()` function in my `main.js` file.

The `useNumber` composable functionality (adding 1 to number) is triggered from within `setup()`.
The `useRandomNumber` functionality (generating a random number) is triggered from within **itself** via `setInterval`.

Both `number.value` and `randomNumber.value` are used inside `index.html` but only `randomNumber` remains reactive.
While both remain reactive inside `setup()`.

Why does the **spreading** not break both variables but only on `number`?

How my example works:
The `randomNumber` is changing onscreen. So this is reactive.
The `number` can be altered by clicking the ADD button. As you will see, the value changes in the console (as this is from within `setup()`) but not on screen from the `return`.

I'd expect that reactivity for both would work OR break due to the spreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a different `number` ref to the template than the one in your script:

```
const { number, addOne } = useNumber(); // <--- creates a "number" ref

    const addToNumber = () => {
      addOne();
      console.log("NUMBER", number.value);
    };

    return {
      ...useNumber(), // <--- creates another "number", the template works on that
      ...useRandomNumber(),
      addToNumber // <--- works on a variable not used in the template
    };
```

To fix it, just return the actual ref:

```
    return {
      ...useRandomNumber(),
      addToNumber, number
    };
```

---

it also works if you keep it as it is, but call the `addOne()` method associated with the `number`:

```html
<button @click="addOne()">Add</button>
```

(of course the `addToNumber()` function is now unused)

---

If you want the number to be the same for each call to `useNumber()`, like a global variable, you have to declare it outside the function:

```
import { ref } from "vue";

const number = ref(0); // <--- there can only be one

export function useNumber() {
  
  const addOne = () => { // <--- could declare that outside as well 
    number.value++;
  };

  return {
    number,
    addOne
  };
}
```